# Automatically print a document when it's moved to a specific folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, printing

Is there any way to automatically print a document when it's moved to a specific folder? I'm really new to SharePoint and all. I would really like to hear which way it could be possible, for example with visual studio. I don't have a clue how and couldn't find something that really helps me.

Thanks in advance

Emi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around for this myself. For anyone who might be interested:

During a process in a Workflow (in my case, when I receive an email with an attachment), I create these files in a folder in my File System, as well in my SharePoint library. Then I have a PowerShell Script that runs daily, which prints out all these files to my default printer and deletes it afterwards.

Here the script:

dir "C:\Test\ *.pdf" | ForEach-Object {Start-Process -FilePath $*.FullName -Verb Print -PassThru | %{sleep 10;$*} | kill}

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test -Include *.* -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}

This way, it still works like I wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

This is not doable through the out of the box functionality, either you should develop a custom workflow or event receiver to handle this... thru this coding approach, we can implement this.

If you are looking for a third party tool, you may go with harepoint printing solution :

https://www.harepoint.com/Blog/sharepoint-printing-feature/

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, SharePoint doesn't provide printing.

To meet your needs, you can look for some other tools.

But I'm afraid they won't give you the ability to print automatically when you move file to a specified folder, which may require you to do it manually.